# How to set autorunscript of core commands?

Tags: android, metasploit, meterpreter, automation

I'm trying to automate scripts of an Android Metasploit payload. I can successfully automate any script on the `/post` module, however, I'm trying to automate `geolocate`, `dump_calllog` and others that are not on the post module. I think from what I searched in the metasploit folders that they are in `/lib/rex` folder. How can I add them in `autorunscript` so that they automate?

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this and wanted to own the process, I'd copy the scripts into the self created scripts section under ~/.msf4 then I'd call the script from there.

here is a link for custom scripting. Some scripts can be added to the /usr/share directory while others need to be placed in ~/.msf4

https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/custom-scripting/

Here is a copy of the geolocation script from google.

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/rex/google/geolocation.rb